# Orthogonal matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

How can I find an orthogonal matrix that can diagonalize the next matrix: $$M = \begin{pmatrix}  \ a & b \\\ b & a \end{pmatrix}, b\ne 0.$$

Another question is how can I find the eigenvalues of this matrix $M$? I think I know the answer for this question. I need to find the characteristic polynomial and so on. Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, $1/\sqrt{2}\,(1,1; -1,1)$. The eigenvectors are clearly $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @PeterFranek - Can you please explain more? Yes what? What do you mean by "1/2√(1,1;−1,1)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvectors are clearly $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ because both vectors are mapped to their multiples by $M$. So, the matrix of orthonormal eigenvectors is 
$$
P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and you can easilly check that $P^{-1} M P$ is diagonal with eigenvalues $a+b$ and $a-b$ on the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

To find the eigenvectors, you need to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial, $\chi_M$, which is given by

$$\chi_M=\det(M-\lambda I_n)$$

Where $I_n$ denotes the identity element for an $n$x$n$ matrix.

The eigenvalues are the roots of $\chi_M$.

If you want a helpful video, try [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4N8vJpf7hM) by patrickJMT.